# Use Realtime Database emulator in flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-web

Is there any way to use the firebase realtime db emulator with flutter web? I know is not yet available in FlutterFire but there might be some workaround.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hi, yeap I was already using that package, didn't find a way around but thanks anyway, your answers are always very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed the FlutterFire plugin for Firebase's Realtime Database does not currently support web clients.

I don't know of a workaround for that plugin, but typically use `package:firebase/firebase.dart` myself when accessing Realtime Database from Flutter Web. I'm not sure if that supports connecting to the emulator yet, but if not, it's probably worth filing a feature request on the [repo](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/issues) or (even better) a PR for it.